# How do you send an attachment with cdo.message if the file is in use

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to send an email in classic asp site with an attachment. I am recieving  the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. "

The file is sitting in a shared folder on the same physical server that is hosting the site. If I check in computer management on the server I can confirm that a user has it open.

My question then is: Am I able to send a copy of the file that is saved to disk using cdo.message if that file is in use? I stripped away the rest of my code to do a test and I was still getting the same error using this.

```
'Create the Message Object
Set objMsg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
'Set the properties of the Message
With objMsg 
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = sFrom
        .To = sTo
        .Subject = sSubject
        .TextBody = sBody 
        .Send 
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't circumvent this restriction nor would you want to else you could be sending a corrupt file.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I tried though with outlook before I even bothered beginning to look and it was able to do it without a problem.

Comment: Curtis:  I dunno what to tell you, imagine if outlook could really breach a read lock on the file (and frankly I would be surprised that it could) and the other process was in middle of updating the file but outlook read it as is and sent it anyway.  It would be sending garbage.  Is this really desirable?